# Why won't Microsoft Edge offer to save basic HTTP auth credentials?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I have a internal web page that that uses basic HTTP authentication for access control. The credentials for this service are not the same as the user's Active Directory credentials. Edge is not showing the usual pop-up to save the login details for this page and users are switching to other browsers to avoid typing the same user and password on a daily basis.

I've checked that Edge does offer to save credentials for other pages that use typical form submitted credentials.

I've tried to add this page to the intranet and trusted sites zones and it still doesn't work. In the intranet zone's case it worsened the problem because by default it uses the user's windows credentials without prompting the user. I changed this behavior in Internet settings (inetcpl.cpl) and I still don't get the prompt to save the credentials.

I also tried to save the credentials manually via Edge's settings and it won't use them.

After a bit of search this appears to be a Chromium based browser issue. With Chrome I get the save credentials prompt using the default settings (no zone assignment).

Any ideas besides changing the app authentication method?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I solved this problem by clicking on the 3 dots menu, and choosing the "Reload in Internet Explorer mode". After doing this, you will see the checkbox to store credentials.